# Do Vampire fangs act as straws?

Tags: vampire

Typical vampire lore features an oral construction that includes a characteristic pair of fangs. Growing up I blithely assumed that these fangs were through what a vampire drank blood, similar to drawing blood with a needle. But lately I have begun to question this.
Do vampires drink through the fangs? Or are the fangs merely to pierce the skin, allowing the vampire to suck blood into their mouth (to be swallowed)?

Comment: I think the answers in the negative below are correct, but I shared the same view as a kid, of vamp fangs essentially as hypodermic needles.

Comment: If you watch dusk till dawn the series they do act like straws :)

Comment: In Mirrodin, one of the planes of Magic: the Gathering, vampires suck blood with creepy syringe-fingernails, which are not fangs, but do act like straws. We live in an age of wonders!

Comment: Maybe I am mistaken, but my impression was that "typical vampire lore" also features victims emptied of any blood, with the only trace being two tiny, easy to miss punctures at the neck. This would indeed strongly speak for the fangs acting as straws, but I currently have no statistical information on how often those small punctures are indeed a part of the story.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This really depends upon which setting you are referring to.  Some vampires could use their fangs not only as hypodermic syringes that could suck up blood as if it were a straw, but could also inject their prey with their own saliva or blood, to facilitate the process of making new vampires, inject anti-coagulants to increase the flow of blood, or even muscle relaxing drugs to ensure their victims don't struggle.

More frequently, though, the fangs are merely to break the skin to provide access to the blood, which is then drank through the mouth much as a human would drink.  This is why you so frequently see vampires with blood dripping from their mouths right after feeding:
[image]

Other depictions show vampires licking up blood:
[image]

This is probably the most accepted version, and actually coincides with the method of "vampire" feeding actually seen in nature:

[image]

[From National Geographic:](http://animals.nationalgeographic.com/animals/mammals/common-vampire-bat/)

> After putting the bite on an animal, the vampire bat laps up the flowing blood with its tongue. Its saliva prevents the blood from clotting.

Comment: I always imagined them as straws too. The anatomy of snake teeth probably helped creating that image.

Comment: There are a few fictional universes where Vampires use them that way; Spider Robinson's Callahan books, for example, have them function as straws, with special organs just past them in the mouth.  It's not that odd of a perception, possibly because many movies showed a puncture from the teeth... and then no movement as they sucked... Assuming they were sucking via the teeth is not unreasonable.

Comment: Snake teeth don't act as straws either - they are injection only

Answer (score 1):

No, the fangs do not act like straws. The fangs are long sharp teeth that are used to penetrate the carotid artery so blood flows out. Although we have several main arteries, the carotid artery in our neck has the largest pace of blood flow throughout our entire body.

In some cases, vampires would put drugs/poisons on their fangs in order to knock out their prey, stun, etc. You get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

No... as Dracula from billy and mandy says "Dracula scrape with his fangs and lick the blood out with his tongue, like this. Scrape and lick" and who are we to argue with the king. Also in the animal kingdom creatures with hollow teeth are usually venemous and inject as aposed to being straws and suck out blood. To further prove my point the animal most associated with the vampire is the bat which drinks blood, it puncture the skin of an animal and lap it up with its tongue

Comment: Why have i been down graded, i suplied evidence in the natural world as well as quoted a vampire who admitted to scraping and licking the blood out

Comment: Probably a combination of poor spelling, grammar, and punctuation, and the fact that you didn't add anything new that wasn't covered by much older answers, not to mention providing less detail than the previously-accepted answer.